# Trouble destroying an SDL2 texture from another class

Tags: sdl2

In my main class (game loop) I have created a couple of object textures:

```
//main game class
    SDL_Texture* objectTexture;
    SDL_Texture* objectTexture2;
```

If I do this in the main class (game loop) the texture doesn't destroy itself, it leaves part of the animated SDL_Rect on the screen. This is the result of when the user clicks pick up on the menu.

```
 gameObject = mob.PickUp(scene,x, y,gd, gy,mInteraction,spriteTexture,objectTexture,objectTexture2,renderer,spriteDown1, "");

        if (gameObject != "") {

            pob.DestroyObjects(gameObject, objectTexture, objectTexture2, renderer);

        }
```

But if I do this in the main class, it works?

```
gameObject = mob.PickUp(scene,x, y,gd, gy,mInteraction,spriteTexture,objectTexture,objectTexture2,renderer,spriteDown1, "");

  if (gameObject == "Object 1!"){


            SDL_DestroyTexture(objectTexture);
            objectTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, NULL);
       }


       if (gameObject == "Object 2!"){


          SDL_DestroyTexture(objectTexture2);
          objectTexture2 = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, NULL);
       }
```

pob.DestroyObjects does the same thing as above code, just in a different class. I have passed the pointers to the other class. I would be tearing my hair out but I have shaved my head during the lockdown.

Answer (score 0):

it was due to the render in the game loop. I had to add a check before the render to confirm if the object had been picked up, so that not to keep rendering the object on each iteration of the game loop.

SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, objectTexture, &srcrect, &dstrect);